# Many-to-many relationship with itself can't utilize the related name attribute

Tags: django, models

I am trying to make a Twitter clone.

The app has a series of users, each of which has a user profile.  The UserProfile model is as follows

```
class UserProfiles(models.Model):
    authenticated_user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="user_profile")

    handle = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    display_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    following = models.ManyToManyField("self", related_name="followers", null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.authenticated_user.handle
```

The "following" attribute is a many-to-many relationship with UserProfiles, as each user profile can follow many other profiles, and many profiles can be following another profile.

If I have an instance of UserProfiles, we'll call it current_user, I can find how many profiles it's following by doing

```
current_user.following.count
```

I also want to be able to tell the user how many people are following them.  Since the related_name argument is set to "followers," it seems reasonable that I can get a count of followers by doing

```
current_user.followers.count
```

This, however, returns an error, "'UserProfiles' object has no attribute 'followers'"

Why won't what I did work?  What can I do instead?

Comment: You ran `makemigrations` and `migrate` after adding the `related_name`?

Answer (score 2):

The default m2m relation to self is symmetrical in django. If you look at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.symmetrical):

> When Django processes this model, it identifies that it has a `ManyToManyField` on itself, and as a result, it doesn’t add a `person_set` attribute to the `Person` class. Instead, the `ManyToManyField` is assumed to be `symmetrica`l – that is, if I am your friend, then you are my friend.
>
> If you do not want symmetry in many-to-many relationships with `self`, set `symmetrical` to `False`. This will force Django to add the descriptor for the reverse relationship, allowing `ManyToManyField` relationships to be non-symmetrical.

In your case since `symmetrical` attribute for the m2m relationship is true, it means:

`A is following B => B is following A`

But if you need both `following` and `followers` relationships you need to set `symmetrical=False`:

```
following = models.ManyToManyField("self", related_name="followers", 
                                   symmetrical=False, null=True)
```