# Related name of a many-to-many relationship in Django

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

I have a model of user like this:

```py
class User(AbstractUser):
    following = models.ManyToManyField('self', related_name="followed")
```

I'm trying to make a many to many relationship from a user to a user. I need to access who the user is following, and who is following the user. The first requirement works nicely, but when I try to see who is following the user, with `user.followed.all()`, I see an error,

> `AttributeError at /user/1: 'User' object has no attribute 'followed'`

How can I fulfill my second requirement?

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct `User` model and not the one builtin in Django (so `django.contrib.auth.models`).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes i am

Comment: Found the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42377899/many-to-many-relationship-with-itself-cant-utilize-the-related-name-attribute?rq=1